# Odd Bug , using File.RenameTo()

Tags: java

I have a program in which i must rename a set of folders. they are all in "ID [Name]" format, and I want to rename them to "Name [ID]". (Its more of a training for me, for learning java))

the problem is, if the number of folders it must rename go beyond 20-24 . the program won't work, and will give the files faulty names. (the renaming process succeeds, but names are wrong)
but if they are below 20 folders, it works perfectly.(tested with the same folders)

here's the whole code:

```
public class DirRename {
private String parentDir;
private DirectoryStream<Path> fileList;

public DirRename(final Path dir)
{
    parentDir = dir.toString();
    if(!Files.exists(dir) || !Files.isDirectory(dir) || !Files.isReadable(dir))
        System.out.println("Directory Read Error!!!");

    //filter to return only directories in parent folder
    DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> dirOnlyFilter =
    new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
        public boolean accept(Path file) throws IOException {
            return (Files.isDirectory(file));
        }
    };

    try
    {
        fileList = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir,dirOnlyFilter);
    }
    catch(IOException | DirectoryIteratorException x)
    {
        System.err.println(x);
    }
}

public void rename()
{
    for(Path filepath : fileList)
    {
        String name = filepath.getFileName().toString();
        File inFile = filepath.toFile();
        if(!inFile.exists() || !inFile.isDirectory() || !inFile.canWrite())
        {
            System.out.println("Directory is not writeable");
            return;
        }
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((?:[\\w\\d]*(?:\\s|-){0,2}[\\w\\d]+)*)\\s*-*\\s*(?:\\[|\\Q(\\E)(.+)(?:\\]|\\Q)\\E)$");
        Matcher match = regex.matcher(name);
        while(match.find())
        {
            String gameID = match.group(1);
            String gameName = match.group(2);
            String rename = parentDir+File.separator+gameName+" ["+gameID+"]";
            File toFile = new File(rename);
            if(!Paths.get(rename).isAbsolute())
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot rename "+name+"to "+rename);
                return;
            }
            if(inFile.renameTo(toFile))
                System.out.println("Success!");
            else
                System.out.println("Renaming Failed!!! for "+rename);
        }
    }

}
}
```

I tried checking the names with "system.out.println(toFile.getName())" while deleting the line "inFile.renameTo(toFile)". all names were correct. 
but when i added that line back, the same names were printed incorrectly.(although some that were printed correctly were renamed incorrectly)

I'm completely confused. and I'm new to java, and generally less than a noob programmer. can someone please tell me what's going on?

Many thanks

**EDIT**: I found the problem.the loop:

```
for(Path filepath : fileList){}
```

runs 116 times while i only have 64 folders. I can't find any explanation as to why this happens, I use the same loop to print folder names only in the following function and it runs exactly 64 times.( exactly the number of folders I have)

```
public void printFolders()
{
    for(Path filepath : fileList)
        System.out.println(filepath.getFileName());
}
```

Comment: Define "won't work". What happens? What is the input and what is the output?

Comment: as I explained above . the naming succeeds but it gives the folders wrong names (some remain the same, some just go plain weird, and then a few are correctly renamed). however if the number of folders it must rename are below 20, all are renamed correctly.

Comment: It probably means that this awful regex is wrong, then. If you provided the inputs and outputs, I might try to identify where the problem comes from. But since you want to keep that secret, my help will remain secret as well.

Comment: as i said. the files are in "ID [Name]" format and I must rename them to "Name [ID]". here's the exact same things I used for testing: http://www.mediafire.com/download/1dkiirrg79ppw6v/names.rar

Comment: the whole thing works when number of folders are below 20. the same names work and are renamed correctly, but go completely wrong when more than 20 folders. so I don't think the regex is wrong.

Comment: Can you give an example where System.out.println(toFile.getName()) got the correct target name but inFile.renameTo(toFile) didn't manage to rename it to that? Also, what platform are you using? The behaviour of rename() is platform-dependent.

Comment: I'm using windows XP 32bit, and from the same files I posted in the comment above. "BCAS20107 [HeavyRain]" toFile.getName() says "HeavyRain [BCAS20107]" (correct rename) . but the file stays the same name, while "BLES01392 [Ace Combat Assault Horizon]" is correctly renamed to "Ace Combat Assault Horizon [BLES01392]" in the same run. in another run with 10 folders only, both are renamed correctly

Comment: `File.renameTo` has ton of issues, particularly on Windows shares. Try using Apache commmons-io [FileUtils.moveDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveDirectory) and let us know how this works out

Comment: using Files.move(), and FileUtils.moveDirectory() , both gave me the same results. I'm guessing the culprit is something else. not the rename. buts its really odd how some names are correct in "toFile" but renaming is done incorrectly. completely confused and clueless !!!!

Comment: I just update the post, now the questions is, how to iterate through DirectoryStream Manually.... I'm too noob for that =/

Comment: My guess is that the stream also loops through the directories you just renamed. So the same directory is seen once, renamed, then seen with its new name. You could simply iterate and store them in a list, then iterate through this list.

Comment: is there any way to close the directoryStream, so it won't update its list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I finally Fixed my own problem. here's my guess on why this happened (I don't know the inner working of DirectoryStream so its just a guess).

when the folders were more than a few, the stream would read the previously renamed folders and add them as new folders, thus they were getting renamed twice. either changing the name back to original, or deforming it (the renaming wasn't designed to be 100% re-applicable).
In case of a few folders, the loop would be over before the stream had the chance to refresh, thus no problems.
so here's how i fixed it. by adding the following method, and iterating through an array of paths instead of the stream.

```
private Path[] getVerifiedPaths()
{
    ArrayList<Path> verifiedFilePaths= new ArrayList<>();
    for(Path filepath : fileList)
        verifiedFilePaths.add(filepath);
    return verifiedFilePaths.toArray(new Path[0]);
}

Path[] filePaths = getVerifiedPaths();
    for(Path filePath : filePaths) { ...rename...}
```

instead of:

```
for(Path filepath : fileList){...rename...}
```

thanks to "JB Nizet" for his suggestion (comment above).